# Concordant maps and their $n$-th powers

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$ continuous maps where $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and $f=g\restriction _X$. Then $f$ and $g$ are called concordant if $f^{-1}(z)$ is a dense subset of $g^{-1}(z)$ for every $z\in f(X)$.

Now, consider the $n$-th powers of $f$ and $g$, that is $f^n:X^n\to Z^n$ and $g:Y^n\to Z^n$ where $f^n(x_1,...,x_n)=\big(f(x_1),...,f(x_n)\big)$ and similarly for $g^n$.

I want to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are concordant, then $f^n$ and $g^n$ are concordant for a fixed $n\ge 1$. Of course, it is easy to see that $f^n$ and $g^n$ are continuous and $g^n\restriction _{X^n}=f^n$.

Now, I take a $z\in f^{n}(X^n)$. Suppose $z=\big(f(x_1),...,f(x_n)\big)$. Then I want to prove that $(f^n)^{-1}(z)$ is a dense subset of $(g^n)^{-1}(z)$.

Let $A\cap (g^n)^{-1}(z)$ a non-empty open subset of $(g^n)^{-1}(z)$, where $A$ is open in $Y^n$. Let $z_i=f(x_i)\in f(X)$. Then, if $\pi_i:Y^n\to Y$ is the $i$-th projection, $\pi_i(A)\cap g^{-1}(z_i)$ is a non-empty open subset of $g^{-1}(z_i)$, therefore $f^{-1}(z_i)\cap \pi_i(A)\cap g^{-1}(z_i)\neq \emptyset$ for each $i$.

I thought if we take a $y_i\in f^{-1}(z_i)\cap \pi_i(A)\cap g^{-1}(z_i)$, then $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in (f^n)^{-1}\cap A\cap (g^n)^{-1}(A)$, but I can't prove it yet.

Any hint? Thanks!